# Can WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE be bypassed without rooting?

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to bypass [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE), which -- as also described at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#FLAG_SECURE -- prevents relevant surfaces from being included in screenshots or displayed through insecure paths.

I would like to avoid rooting the device, while being able to take screenshots or use tools such as TeamViewer.

Comment: Edited to make the title descriptive enough that a reader can understand the question without needing to click through, and to not be asking for a link to a preexisting application (which is #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It would be helpful if you described more about your use case. Is it the "doesn't appear in screenshots" behavior you want to bypass, or the "not displayed except on secure displays" one, f/e?

Comment: I cannot take a screenshot of the application and a black screen appears when I try to control the application via teamviewer.

Comment: Is this a question about configuring a device to let you remote-control or screenshot someone else's application (which you're not developing, or developing tools that integrate with)? If this is more a configuration question than a software-development one, our sister site [android.se] may be the better place for it.

Comment: Many applications do not allow you to take screenshots and control them remotely. I'm looking for something that will allow me to bypass this.

Comment: This would be a major security flaw. So, one hopes that it is not possible.